# MVC5 Calling function on MapRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In our site we are making something like "GodMode", when this mode is enable, we want to have data display differently than regular public website. For example, if a user visit

```
http://domain/Home/Index
```

He will see regular public page. but in same browser/session if he visit

```
http://domain/godmode/Home/Index
```

then we want to show other information. For this I create a Static boolean Variable that I `wish` to set when we detect if `godmode` is On. So, I am looking a way to do this. Any Idea how can I set this variable? Or what is best place to set it. so both URL can run in Same Session without interrupt from each other.

As I know `Application_BeginRequest` in Global.asax is for Application level start, not per URL request. I didn't found any relevant replacement for it. Can anyone please suggest one or if we can call a function in MVC `MapRoute` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about an ActionFilteR? I use them to switch languages like this:

```
    public class InternationalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The logger
        /// </summary>
        private NLog.Logger logger;

        private NLog.Logger Logger
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.logger == null)
                {
                    this.logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
                }

                return this.logger;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Is called from the ASP.net framework before a method is executed
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filterContext">The filter context.</param>
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string language = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"] ?? "de";
            string culture = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["culture"] ?? "DE";

            try
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format("{0}-{1}", language, culture));
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format("{0}-{1}", language, culture));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //// not supported culture, falling to default
                this.Logger.Error(string.Format("Invalid culture '{0}-{1}', could not be set", language, culture), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Maproute function:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                "DefaultLocalizedQuestionManagementArea",
                "{language}-{culture}/{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index",
                    id = string.Empty,
                    language = "de",
                    culture = "DE"
                });
```

Finally, every controller ha sto be prefixed with the Attribute like this:

```
  [InternationalizationAttribute]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it and seems working for now. +1 as this is something new for me to learn.

Comment: When I learned this method I was surprised how powerful it is - I love it ;)